# Azure VM Backup Taking Longer Than Expected

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, backup, azure-backup-vault

I am taking backups of my Azure VM using Azure Recovery Service Vault. When I checked the backup recovery points, I noticed that it's taking a time up to 4 to 5 hours, but initially, it only took a snapshot for 10 minutes. It is a scheduled backup that runs once a day during off-hours

[image]

By getting it's more details have noticed it is taking time in Transfer data to vault

[image]

What is difference between Snapshot and Transfer Data to Vault?
Is this the default behavior, or could there be a specific reason for this duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is difference between Snapshot and Transfer Data to Vault?  Is this the default behaviour, or could there be a specific reason for this duration?

While taking the `Backup` of VM to Recovery Service Vault contains two stages

**1.Snapshot** ensures the availability of a recovery point stored alongside the disks, making it suitable for `Instant Restores`. These snapshots remain accessible for up to five days, depending on the user's configured snapshot retention settings.

**2.Transfer data to vault** : During the `Transfer data` to vault phase, a recovery point is established within the vault for long-term retention. This phase initiates only after the completion of the snapshot phase

At the backend, two `Sub Tasks` are in progress—one for the `front-end backup job`, which can be viewed in the `Backup Job` details pane as shown below

[image]

The completion time of the `Transfer data to vault` phase may be lengthy, influenced by factors such as disk size, churn per disk, and various other considerations.

Reference: [Back up Azure VMs in a Recovery Services vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-vms-prepare#verify-backup-job-status)

Comment: backup data activity take 4 + hours during this time , are user/application suffered who are login or hosted on VM ?

Comment: Backup time depending on your internet speed and other parameters.refere this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-vms-prepare#verify-backup-job-status) for more details

Comment: My concern is whether the VM's performance will be affected during the backup process, causing any downtime or issues for users or applications on that VM ?

Comment: During the backup process in Azure, there should be minimal to no downtime for your VM, and the impact on performance for users and applications running on the VM is generally low. it's always a best practice to plan your backup strategy carefully, schedule backups at suitable times, and proactively monitor your VM's performance to ensure it meets your application and user requirements.

Comment: Acknowledged....